# A proper way of using Perl custom modules inside of other Perl modules

Tags: eclipse, perl, module, include, epic

I'm using custom modules in my scripts and have to store them outside of Perl `lib` directory. So in Perl scripts (`*.pl`) I use the following block to include them in `@INC`:

```
BEGIN {
  use FindBin qw($Bin);
  push @INC, "$Bin/../ModulesFolder1";
  push @INC, "$Bin/../ModulesFolder2";
}
```

But I also have to use modules inside of my other Perl modules (`*.pm`), and as I understand `FindBin` works for scripts only. So I change that block to:

```
BEGIN {
  push @INC, catdir( dirname( $INC{'ThisModule.pm'} ), qw( .. ModulesFolder1 ) );
  push @INC, catdir( dirname( $INC{'ThisModule.pm'} ), qw( .. ModulesFolder2 ) );
}
```

It works but with a little problem. I code in Eclipse with EPIC plugin, and ["if you have something in a BEGIN block that causes the compiler to abort prematurely, it won't report syntax errors to  EPIC"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/forums/forum/258688/topic/5474748), so that way I loose Perl syntax check in modules.
So, with `FindBin` (in scripts) I don't have to use any functions (like `catdir`) in `BEGIN{}` block, and the syntax check of the following code goes on correctly. Besides, I'd like not to change any environment variables (like `PERL5LIB`), so that I could use the scripts on my colleagues' machines without any additional preparations.

What's the proper way of using custom Perl modules inside of other modules, and not interfering with EPIC syntax check at the same time? Or maybe I even should include modules in completely other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly disagree with modifying `@INC` in modules. It causes all kinds of headaches. Let the script (or even the calling process via the `PERL5LIB` environment variable) setup `@INC` correctly.

`script.pl`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib
   "$RealBin/../ModulesFolder1",
   "$RealBin/../ModulesFolder2";

use ModuleInFolder1;
```

`ModuleInFolder1.pm`:

```
use ModuleInFolder2;  # Works fine.
```

---

As for EPIC, do the following:

1. Right-click on the project.
2. Properties
3. Perl Include Path
4. `${project_loc}/ModulesFolder1`, Add to list
5. `${project_loc}/ModulesFolder2`, Add to list

(I literally mean the 14 chars `${project_loc}`. That means something to EPIC. It will continue to work even if you move the project.)

---

PS — `$RealBin` is better than `$Bin` because it allows you to use a symlink to your script.

PS — `__FILE__` is more appropriate than `$INC{'ThisModule.pm'}`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Eclipse, but you can use [use lib](http://p3rl.org/lib) (will probably not work, it changes `@INC` at compile time) or set the environment variable `PERL5LIB` to point to your library folder(s).

Comment: As I see, there'd be the same problem with `use lib`. The main idea is that with `FindBin` I don't have to use any functions (like `catdir`) in `BEGIN{}` block, and the syntax check of the following code goes on correctly (please, refer to the link above). I'll made corrections to the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Set up `PERL5LIB` environment variable. Every time you use or require, Perl will check all directories listed in it.

Alternatively, place all necessary custom modules under script's directory, so you can use relative paths in `use lib`. It will also allow you to quickly make a bundle to transfer everything to another PC by just packing recursively from top-level directory.

Comment: I need to make this script fully portable, so that it could be used on my colleagues's PCs without any additional preparations. So, it needs to run properly without modifying environment variables.

Comment: @evgeny9: Then stick to `require` instead of `use`.

Comment: @evgeny9, why not just keep everything under single top-level directory then?

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov We trying to come to this, but for now the structure of the folders in common environment (under SVN) is rather complicated, so I have to address to smb. else's modules.

Comment: @choroba: I tried to use `require`/`import`, but it led to some syntax check errors (likely, because `use` loads the module at compile time, not run-time, and `require` doesn't, thus leading to possible lack of symbols and semantics).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (from my colleague) - a change to be made in the module:

```
sub path_to_current_module() {
  my $package_name = __PACKAGE__ .'.pm';
  $package_name =~ s#::#/#g;

  for my $path ( @INC ) {
    # print "\$path == '$path'\n";
    if ( -e catfile( $path, $package_name ) ) {
      return $path;
    }
  }

  confess;
}

BEGIN {
  my $path_to_current_module = path_to_current_module();
  push @INC, catdir( $path_to_current_module, qw( .. ModulesFolder1 ) );
  push @INC, catdir( $path_to_current_module, qw( .. ModulesFolder2 ) );
}
```

It seems that the old way (described in the question) Perl couldn't locate current module name in `@INC` - that's why `perl -c` was interrupted by error inside of the `BEGIN` block. And the described sub helps it to determine the real path to the current module. Besides, it doesn't depend on the current file name and can be copied to another module.